# How to override model state error message in asp.net Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, modelstate, asp.net-core-2.1

I can't seem to be able to override the error message from model state validation for `int` or nullable ones `int?`. In the previous versions of Asp.Net Core I used to receive that the input is not valid, now I am getting this unfriendly error,

> {"streetNo":["Could not convert string to integer: abc. Path 'cityId',
>   line 24, position 23."]}

so I am trying to work around it using custom validation attribute,

I created this class,

```
 public class IsInt : ValidationAttribute {
        public IsInt () : base () { }

        public override bool IsValid (object value) {
            Console.WriteLine (value);
            if (value.IsNullObject ()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                if (value.GetType () == typeof (int?)) {
                    return true;

                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid (
            Object value,
            ValidationContext validationContext) {

            var message = "Only number is allowed";
            return new ValidationResult (message);
        }
    }
```

and I implement it this way,

```
[IsInt]
public int? StreetNo { get; set; }
```

The validation attribute does not seem to work as intended, if I enter a string, i.e. "abc" I still receive the mentioned model error message, it only works if the string has numbers in it, i.e. "83444"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I wanted to override the messages so they wouldn't always show "The field MyLongDescriptivePropertyName must be a number" directly to the user.  Turns out there is an easy way to do this inside `Startup.cs`:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // MVC
        services.AddMvc(o =>
        {
            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustBeANumberAccessor(val => "Must be a number.");
        });
    }
```

[The class description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.metadata.defaultmodelbindingmessageprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.1) doesn't really explain or give examples.  I found [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/05/09/aspnetcore-mvc-error-message/) which was close, but they've added the `Set...Accessor()` methods since then so that's how you assign for now.

Comment: Does this also work if I'm using [ApiController]? because it didn't work for me